# How to add a logo to a Twitter bootstrap navbar?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a logo which has the dimension of 2829 × 1913 and it is a PNG. How do i fit it into a navbar bootstrap?

Here's the code

```
<div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
        <img src="startupclone202.png">
      </a>
    </div>
```

[image]

How do i change the project name to my own logo that is 2829 × 1913 to a nicely fit logo?

Comment: Post the current code that you are using to create that output and the logo URL. Trim the logo using image editor and use it.

Comment: please put some code so that any one can help

Comment: For bandwidth sake..don't you think the image is too big?

Answer (score 1):

To insert image in navbar use this code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img alt="Brand" src="...">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

For the image download [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) and resize it, is too big.

Comment: I should resize it to what size? for bootstrap navbar?

Comment: the navbar is resized according to the placed image. For my experience is better to place the logo outside the navbar. If you don't want to resize the navbar, the image must have 20px height.

Comment: so the code that you provided could solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

For that first you have to resize the image then You can try the following code for the navbar.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
       <div class="navbar-inner">
         <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"> <imgsrc="images/xyz.jpg"></a>
```

For that you have to add following css

```
.navbar-brand > img {
      max-height: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      -o-object-fit: contain;
      object-fit: contain;
    }
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: what is the appropriate image size for a twitter navbar?

Comment: I did't resize the image, and I tried to use your css codes and it doesnt work, it changed the image to 46 * 60 pixels

Comment: You dont want to change the image pixel?